# Why do I need to set bigger stacksize than it actually should be?

Tags: c, stack, pthreads

I'm trying to analyse this code, which is using pthreads and stacks:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define NTHREADS    8
#define ARRAY_SIZE      500000
#define MEGEXTRA        1000000

pthread_attr_t attr;

void *Hello(void *threadid)
{
   double A[ARRAY_SIZE];
   int i;
   long tid;
   size_t mystacksize;

   tid = (long)threadid;
   sleep(3);
   for (i=0; i<ARRAY_SIZE; i++)
   {
      A[i] = i * 1.0;
   }
   printf("%ld: Hello World!   %f\n", tid, A[ARRAY_SIZE-1]);
   pthread_attr_getstacksize (&attr, &mystacksize);
   printf("%ld: Thread stack size = %li bytes \n", tid, mystacksize);
   pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pthread_t threads[NTHREADS];
    size_t stacksize;
    int rc; 
    long t;
    pthread_attr_init(&attr);
    stacksize = ARRAY_SIZE*sizeof(double) + MEGEXTRA;
    pthread_attr_setstacksize (&attr, stacksize);
    pthread_attr_getstacksize (&attr, &stacksize);
    printf("Thread stack size = %li bytes (hint, hint)\n",stacksize);
    for(t=0;t<NTHREADS;t++){
      rc = pthread_create(&threads[t], &attr, Hello, (void *)t);
        if (rc){
          printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is %d\n", rc);
          exit(-1);
          }
      }
    printf("Created %ld threads.\n", t);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

and I can't figure out this part

```
#define MEGEXTRA        1000000
(...)
stacksize = ARRAY_SIZE*sizeof(double) + MEGEXTRA;
pthread_attr_setstacksize (&attr, stacksize);
pthread_attr_getstacksize (&attr, &stacksize);
```

Why do I need to add this MEGEXTRA value to stacksize. I mean, why without adding this value, the program segfaults.

Comment: With `ARRAY_SIZE*sizeof(double)` you have space for the array `A`, but you need additional stack space for other local variables, function calls and so on.

Comment: No, you need to set the stacksize to be exactly enough as big as it needs to. The problem is, you are not calculating the needed stacksize correctly.

Comment: @KamilCuk so how should I calculate it? is there a better way?

Comment: OT:  the posted code is missing the statement: `#include <unistd.h>`  to expose the prototype for the function: `sleep()`

Comment: OT: regarding: `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`  when the `main()` function parameters are not going to be used, then to avoid two warning messages from the compiler about unused parameters, use the signature: `int main( void )`

Comment: OT: regarding: `printf("Created %ld threads.\n", t);`  immediately after this statement should be a loop calling `pthread_join()` for each thread.

Comment: @Kamill4525 You can't reliably "calculate" the stack usage. Because it is dependent on the compiler. The compiler may be good at optimizing code, or it may be bad, or worse. There is padding between variables, there are alignment issues, hard vs soft float abis, compiler may remove the code without side effects, etc. You can compile your function into a library, inspect generated assembly line by line, count the number of pushes + include hardware / system extra added stack usage. Each time you compile your code, the compiler may generate different code, with different stack usage.

Comment: Your function looks like the whole array calculation may be just 
 optimized to `printf("... %f", 499999.0);`. Why would the compiler even bother with calculating all the values in the array, if you use just one value? You can't reliably "calculate" that (unless you write a compiler that does...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you create a `pthread`, the pthread library must allocate some stack space for it. That doesn't necessarily allocate *physical memory* for the stack space, it allocates virtual address space for the stack. The default stack size allocated for a thread is implementation-dependent, but if you are then going to allocate a large array on the stack (which is where *automatic* storage class variables are placed in virtually all C implementations), you need to adjust the space allocated to ensure it's large enough.

Consider: let's say the implementation (in the pthreads library) has decided to allocate 2MB of stack space, by default, for each thread. Then after creating 3 threads, your virtual memory map might look something like this (exact addresses and other details will of course vary):

```
8060000-8080000           Thread 3 stack
8030000-8050000           Thread 2 stack
8000000-8020000           Thread 1 stack

7000000-8000000           Main thread stack
[...]                     Other program regions (program code, heap, initialized data, library code/data, etc)
```

A couple of things to note. Stacks grow downward. The stack pointer starts out right at the top of the allocated region, and as you push things onto the stack by calling a sub-routine or allocating space for local variables, the stack pointer is reduced. The kernel will generally *not* allocate actual physical pages for your stack immediately. That would be wasteful since you might never use them (and something else would probably have to be evicted from RAM to do that). Instead, *page map entries* for each page in the region are allocated, but marked empty. Then, as you attempt to write into each page, your program will get a page fault. The kernel handles the fault by allocating a physical page for you, mapping it to the right virtual address and updating the page map entry (then automatically resuming your program without your needing to be aware of any of this).

Note also that the stack regions are not immediately contiguous. That is so that the kernel can distinguish when you have exhausted the virtual address space by going too far. *That* is what leads to a segmentation violation in your scenario: you've blown off the bottom of the stack and advanced into space for which there are no page map entries allocated.

So, when you use `pthread_attr_setstacksize`, you're telling the library and the kernel that you know exactly how large to make the stack and configuring the memory map accordingly. But since you have only provided enough space to *exactly* contain the array, you haven't left any room for the stack frame used to invoke your thread function, or for its other local variables (`tid`, `i`, `mystacksize`), or for any padding or other local stack usage.

So, the original author of this code was essentially saying: "I need to ensure there is room in each thread for my big array and then throw in an additional `MEGEXTRA` bytes for local variables, the calling stack frame and any other overhead." Again, note that is only allocating *virtual address space* so it's not wasteful to do this (virtual address space is not generally a precious resource on a 64-bit architecture). In the actual running of the program, you are likely only *using* one or two additional pages of that additional space.

One other thing to note: the first part of the stack size calculation (`ARRAY_SIZE*sizeof(double)`) equals 4 million. In hex, that is, 0x3D0900, which is *not* a multiple of the page size (usually 4K or 0x1000). The result of using that figure is indeterminate. The kernel might expand that to the next page size boundary (0x3d10000), or it might truncate to the previous boundary (0x3d0000), or (according to linux man page) it might return an error.

The posix specification (http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_attr_setstacksize.html) says

> The stacksize attribute shall define the minimum stack size (in bytes) allocated for the created threads stack.

and says nothing about non-page-aligned size so arguably, expanding the size to the next page boundary is the only *correct* behavior. But glibc does not seem to do such an adjustment and the linux kernel implementation appears to then truncate the size provided.

In any case, it's a good idea not to cut these things too close. Predicting your actual exact stack usage in a real-life program is difficult at best.